# bootstrap datepicker doesn't show calendar on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

So I'm making a custom component for Design Studio in Eclipse. And I'm trying to make a bootstrap datepicker. So I included bootstrap(v4) and bootstrap-datepicker in my project (both css and js files see code). Now the problem is everytime I load the page and click the datepicker the calendar doesn't show on my screen. The weird part is that I when i pressed f12 to check my errors: 1) I had no errors displayed 2) when I click the datepicker after I pressed f12 it does show the calendar but it will be completely bugged(the calendar gets showed and I can select dates but it's fixed floating in the air and won't close anymore even when I press outside the datepicker see screenshot).

code:

```
//scripts               component           d3          ckeditor                        my own css              bootstrap.js(v4)                    bootrap-datepicker.js                                   bootstrap.css                               bootstrap-datepicker3.css                           select2.css                             select2.js                  font-awsome
define(["sap/designstudio/sdk/component", "d3", "../js/ckeditor/ckeditor", "css!../css/component.css", "../js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min", "../js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min", "css!../js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", "css!../js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css", "css!../js/dist/css/select2.min.css", "../js/dist/js/select2.min", "css!../js/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"], function(Component, d3, ckeditor, css) {
Component.subclass("com.sap.sample.annotation.Annotation", function() {

    //this stands in a function that gets called didn't wanne annoy you guys with 500 lines of code
    dateYearMonth = theDiagram.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("x", "5%")
        .attr("y", "90%")
        .attr("width", "200")
        .attr("height", "50")
        .append("xhtml:body")
            //.style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
        .html('<div class="span5 col-md-5" id="sandbox-container"><input class="form-control" type="text"></div>');

        //datepicker
        $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
            });

});
});
```

Images(take note the calendar only shows up after I click the input after pressing f12 else it won't even show):

[image: screen after I pressed f12 and closed it]

[image: calendar that pops up after I press f12]

Anyone has some ideas to fix this cause I'm all out.

**EDIT:**

I just also saw that everytime I click the datepicker this generates a new datepicker in the code but it's display is none;

Image:
[image]